# How to use grep in function(x)

Tags: r, regex

If I want to use the grep in function(x) to search for strings exactly, what can I do? I took an existing example,

```
  > string = c("apple", "apples", "applez")                       
  > grep("apple", string)
```

This would return all three and just one with exactly "apple" is possible by using "word boundary \b", but in the above case....

In this scenario

```
  > lapply(V4, function(x) df$V2[grep(x,df$V1, fixed = TRUE)]))
```

how can I achieve the same?

Comment: Can you use anchors: `grep("apple$", string)`

Comment: How can I do exact string search in second scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the square bracket operator, which acts as a filter

```
string = c("apple", "apples", "applez")  

string[string == "apple"]
# [1] "apple"
```

Comment: How can I do exact string search in second scenario?

Comment: Maybe like: `lapply(V4, function(x) df$V2[x == df$V1]))`